# NSView within NSScrollView not sizing properly (trying to size DocumentView programmatically)

Tags: macos, nsview, nsscrollview

**ADDITION #2**
I have also tried getting the size using these lines of code for contSizeW and contSizeWO:

```
NSSize contSizeW  = [NSScrollView contentSizeForFrameSize:self.topLevelScroller.frame.size
                                  horizontalScrollerClass:[self.topLevelScroller.horizontalScroller class]
                                    verticalScrollerClass:nil
                                               borderType:self.topLevelScroller.borderType
                                              controlSize:NSRegularControlSize
                                            scrollerStyle:NSScrollerStyleOverlay];
NSSize contSizeWO = [NSScrollView contentSizeForFrameSize:self.topLevelScroller.frame.size
                                  horizontalScrollerClass:nil
                                    verticalScrollerClass:nil
                                               borderType:self.topLevelScroller.borderType
                                              controlSize:NSRegularControlSize
                                            scrollerStyle:NSScrollerStyleOverlay];
```

These above 2 sizes, SHOULD be different as one sets horizontalScrollerClass to `nil`, which by apples documentation means it should assume the scroller to not be visible, and by providing a non-nil, should assume it to be showing the scroller.

In this case it is ALWAYS returning the same height regardless of what I put in for horizontalScrollerClass.

**EDIT & ADDITION #1**

```
-(void)initContentView{
    self.content = [[NSView alloc] init];
    [self.content setFrame:NSMakeRect(1, 1, 
                                      [[BubbleSharedPathObject sharedPath] itemsInPathList] * FILE_LIST_COLUMN_WIDTH, 
                                      self.bounds.size.height - 2)];
    [self.content setAutoresizingMask:NSViewMinXMargin | NSViewMinYMargin |
                                      NSViewMaxYMargin | NSViewHeightSizable];
    [self.content setAutoresizesSubviews:YES];
    [self.topLevelScroller setDocumentView:self.content];
```

}

**ORIGINAL**
I have a custom view that I am attempting to size programmatically.  My NSScrollView is set to have only a horizontal scroller, and no vertical scroller.  The ScrollView is also set to auto hide the scrollers.  I have a routine called:

```
-(void)addPathComponentToEnd:(NSString *)pathComp
```

This routine will only add width to the custom view that holds contents and is the document view for the ScrollView.  The snippet of code that is interestingly not working is:

```
[self.topLevelScroller setAutoresizesSubviews:NO];
[self.content setAutoresizesSubviews:NO];

NSSize contSizeW  = [NSScrollView contentSizeForFrameSize:self.topLevelScroller.frame.size hasHorizontalScroller:YES hasVerticalScroller:NO borderType:self.topLevelScroller.borderType];
NSSize contSizeWO = [NSScrollView contentSizeForFrameSize:self.topLevelScroller.frame.size hasHorizontalScroller:NO hasVerticalScroller:NO borderType:self.topLevelScroller.borderType];

NSLog(@"Size With = (%d, %d), Size Without = (%d, %d)", (unsigned int)contSizeW.width, (unsigned int)contSizeW.height, (unsigned int)contSizeWO.width, (unsigned int)contSizeWO.height);

// Resize the content view to handle the added list view
if( ( [[BubbleSharedPathObject sharedPath] itemsInPathList] * FILE_LIST_COLUMN_WIDTH ) > contSizeW.width ){
    [self.content setFrameSize:NSMakeSize([[BubbleSharedPathObject sharedPath] itemsInPathList] * FILE_LIST_COLUMN_WIDTH + 2, contSizeW.height)];

    for(FileListTableView * table in self.tablesList){
        //[table setFrame:NSMakeRect(table.fileList.tag * FILE_LIST_COLUMN_WIDTH, 0, FILE_LIST_COLUMN_WIDTH, self.content.frame.size.height)];
        [table setFrameSize:NSMakeSize(FILE_LIST_COLUMN_WIDTH, contSizeW.height)];
        NSLog(@"file list table height = %d", (unsigned int)table.frame.size.height);
    }

    NSLog(@"New Rect (x, y, w, h) = (%d, %d, %d, %d)", (unsigned int)self.content.frame.origin.x, (unsigned int)self.content.frame.origin.y, (unsigned int)self.content.frame.size.width, (unsigned int)self.content.frame.size.height);
}else{
    [self.content setFrame:NSMakeRect(1, 1, [[BubbleSharedPathObject sharedPath] itemsInPathList] * FILE_LIST_COLUMN_WIDTH + 2, contSizeWO.height)];
    //[self.content setFrame:NSMakeRect(1, 1, [[BubbleSharedPathObject sharedPath] itemsInPathList] * FILE_LIST_COLUMN_WIDTH, self.frame.size.height - 2)];

    NSLog(@"New Rect (x, y, w, h) = (%d, %d, %d, %d)", (unsigned int)self.content.frame.origin.x, (unsigned int)self.content.frame.origin.y, (unsigned int)self.content.frame.size.width, (unsigned int)self.content.frame.size.height);
}
```

The output from the logging with multiple calls to the subroutine containing this code is as follows:

```
Size With = (501, 206), Size Without = (501, 221)
New Rect (x, y, w, h) = (1, 1, 402, 221)
Size With = (501, 206), Size Without = (501, 221)
file list table height = 206
file list table height = 206
New Rect (x, y, w, h) = (1, 0, 602, 192)
Size With = (501, 206), Size Without = (501, 221)
file list table height = 206
file list table height = 206
file list table height = 206
New Rect (x, y, w, h) = (1, 0, 802, 206)
```

The code:

```
[[BubbleSharedPathObject sharedPath] itemsInPathList]
```

initially only returns 1, so all subsequent calls will add 1, thus that should (and I have verified) that it returns 1, then 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 and so on.

Notice from the logging that the first time the code moves through the "if" (versus the else) that the logging shows the self.content view not taking the height value of 206 that it should, and is SOMEHOW coming up with its own value of 192.  Also notice that in the call after that one (and verified all others after) actually finally DO take the proper value of 206 height.

QUESTION:
Why is the view not taking on the size that I am assigning to it?  Has anyone else seen this type of behavior before, how did you fix it?

Thanks much in advance.

Comment: @MacUserT - was there a question to go along with the hello :-)

Comment: Hi Trumpetlicks, I've been reading your code and have some questions. Your snippet starts with setting the NSSize of contSizeW and contSizeWO.  Then yo reach the if statement that, as I read your log correctly first comes up with false, because from the log I read it goes to the "else" statement and sets the frame of self.content to 1, 1, 402, 221. What I fail to see, is how the program returns to the if statement under the comment //Resize ..., what the value of FILE_LIST_COLUMN_WIDTH is and what the relation between contentSizeW and self.content.frame.size is. Did I miss something?

Comment: @MacUserT - So that whole routine is called from an external action, when that external action occurs, an update occurs to a set of data.  That data is what essentially drives `[[BubbleSharedPathObject sharedPath] itemsInPathList]', contSizeW is supposed to be the content size capability of the scrollview when the horizontal scroller is present, and ContSizeWo is the size capability of the scrollview when the horizontal scroller is not present.  The if statement is there to figure out if the content with the new addition will be WIDER than the scroller frame capability.

Comment: @MacUserT - Cont. from above.  I never want the content view to be taller than the scrollviews VISIBLE area can provide, only to be WIDER.  Thus what I am trying to accomplish is to recognize when my content is wider, and account for the visible frame loss that occurs when the horizontal scroller WILL BECOME present.  Regardless, I still don't understand how when I am calculating, and directly setting the view to be of height 206, as presented by `ContSizeW`, that it is not only not taking that number, but also not keeping the one it had before, and coming up with something completely new.

Comment: Hi trumpetlicks, thanks that helps. I'm sorry for keep asking without giving you a solution. Here is my problem. Your class that has the method of this code snippet holds an array of tables of class FileListTableView. The first time the column width is larger than contSizeW, you set the frame size of the table in the table list to FILE_LIST_COLUMN_WIDTH (which I assume is the designated column width the table should have. After setting the column width of all the tables you log the dimensions of rectangle self.content.

Comment: -cont. from above.- I'm missing where the self.content dimensions are changed from the initial values set during the else statement or the relation between the table frame size and the self.content dimensions.

Comment: By the way, do you know you are using a deprecated method?

Comment: @MacUserT - I have no probe with the questions, keep em' coming :-) My current version of Xcode and the APIs is not flagging a deprecated method at this point, but I believe you LOL.  The initial size of self.content is actually setup in the containing object's init methods.  This addPathComponentToEnd routine is called post init, and only on an action by the user.  The user will select an item from the list defined by (essentially) `[[BubbleSharedPathObject sharedPath] itemsInPathList]` equals 0, at that point a routine adds a list to that BubbleSharedPathObject and thus it will be +1 ...

Comment: @MacUserT -cont. - prior to the call to addPathComponentToEnd.  The if statement itself checks what the NEW width will be based upon the count of lists within the SharedPath object which should now be 2.  @ it will move through the else clause still, @ 3 is when it moves through the if clause for the first time, and after 3 will go through the if clause as well (This is for the test case where I HAVE NOT resized the window)

Comment: @MacUserT - I added the initialization code for the document view within the question.  That routine is called from within my object's init, initWithCoder, and initWithFrame routines, and at this point, the `[[BubbleSharedPathObject sharedPath] itemsInPathList]` is already returning 1.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your explanation I think I understand your routine and it is indeed odd that you get the log first with 192 and then 206 again. However, (unsigned int)self.content.frame.size.height is set by contSizeW, which again is set by the deprecated method 
contentSizeForFrameSize:hasHorizontalScroller:hasVerticalScroller:borderType:

According to the Xcode 6.1.1 documentation and API reference this method is deprecated since OS X 10.7 and you should use: contentSizeForFrameSize:horizontalScrollerClass:verticalScrollerClass:borderType:controlSize:scrollerStyle: instead. It also states that for existing views you can simply use the contentSize method.

Can you, please, use either one of these methods, instead of the deprecated one and see if the problem is solved. If this doesn't help, I'm as stuck as you are.

Here is the documentation on the method. Sorry for not being able to give you an easy solution.

> contentSizeForFrameSize:horizontalScrollerClass:verticalScrollerClass:borderType:controlSize:scrollerStyle:
>   Returns the content size calculated from the frame size and the
>   specified specifications.
>
> Declaration SWIFT class func contentSizeForFrameSize(_ frameSize:
>   NSSize,
>              horizontalScrollerClass horizontalScrollerClass: AnyClass?,
>                verticalScrollerClass verticalScrollerClass: AnyClass?,
>                           borderType borderType: NSBorderType,
>                          controlSize controlSize: NSControlSize,
>                        scrollerStyle scrollerStyle: NSScrollerStyle) -> NSSize OBJECTIVE-C
>   + (NSSize)contentSizeForFrameSize:(NSSize)frameSize
>             horizontalScrollerClass:(Class)horizontalScrollerClass
>               verticalScrollerClass:(Class)verticalScrollerClass
>                          borderType:(NSBorderType)borderType
>                         controlSize:(NSControlSize)controlSize
>                       scrollerStyle:(NSScrollerStyle)scrollerStyle Parameters frameSize  The frame size in screen coordinates.
>   horizontalScrollerClass    The class used as the horizontal scroller. A
>   value of nil specifies that no horizontal scroller is used.
>   verticalScrollerClass  The class used as the vertical scroller. A
>   value of nil specifies that no horizontal scroller is used.
>   borderType     Specifies the appearance of the style of the scroll view’s
>   border. See NSBorderType for a list of possible values. controlSize
>   The control size. The possible values are specified in NSControlSize.
>   NSMiniControlSize is not supported. scrollerStyle  Specifies the
>   scroll style. See NSScrollerStyle for supported values. Return Value
>   The content view frame size.
>
> Discussion For an existing scroll view, you can simply use the
>   contentSize method.
>
> Import Statement import AppKit
>
> Availability Available in OS X v10.7 and later.

Comment: So I actually just now, and I remember trying this last night, doesn't work either.  In fact, that routine from apple doesn't actually work properly.  If you notice from edit 2 in the question, by setting horizontalScrollerClass to nil, the routine should return a different height for the 2, but doesn't it returns 221 ALWAYS, meaning it doesn't know its own difference between the scroller being visible and the scroller not being visible LOL